# Oracle SQL PLS-00103 Error when creating the package body

Tags: sql, oracle, package, pls-00103

**I receive the following error:**

> The create package operation was not successful for the following
>   reason:  ERROR at line 41: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: end not pragma
>   final instantiable order overriding static member constructor map

**The code is as follows:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY update_quantity 
IS

PROCEDURE set_new_quantity(product_idProduct IN NUMBER, order_idOrder IN NUMBER, newquantity IN    NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
 UPDATE Order_item o
 SET o.quantity = newquantity
 WHERE o.product_idProduct = product_idProduct     
        AND o.order_idOrder = order_idOrder; 

--EXCEPTION
      --WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 --RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20100, 'No such quantity or order');

END set_new_quantity;

FUNCTION FUNCTION existing_quantity_f(product_idProduct IN NUMBER, order_idOrder IN NUMBER)  RETURN NUMBER

IS

existing_newquantity NUMBER(4);

BEGIN
SELECT o.quantity INTO existing_newquantity 
FROM ORDER_item o
WHERE
        o.product_idProduct = product_idProduct     
        AND o.order_idOrder = order_idOrder; 

RETURN (existing_newquantity);

--EXCEPTION
     -- WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
--RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20100, 'No such employee or project');

END existing_quantity_f;
```

I have commented out the exception, as initially thought this might be a problem, but the error is still there.

Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following statement at the end of the package body

```
END update_quantity;
```